# How to stop a traffic capture?

Tags: network-traffic

I have created a topology on GNS3. I started a capture with the command -

```
capture R5 f0/0 ping.cap
```

How do I stop the capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTRL+C or `killall capture` or find the prcess ID and `kill $pid`